# ROS kinetic - visualisation of raw data from LiDAR scanner

Tags: mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have set up ROS kinetic environment. I am looking for tips which tools/tutorials should I use to visualise my raw data. What I have is .xml file and .pcd files which was taken by LiDAR (point cloud library). I have also .bag file. I would really aprreciate if you guide me on proper road where should I look for informations about. I have basic understanding of this environment.

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271047/ros-kinetic---visualisation-of-raw-data-from-lidar-scanner/) by [RafMil](https://answers.ros.org/users/30506/rafmil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-09-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rviz` would be the easy to go built-in tool to visualize .pcd and .bag files. You can do a bunch of stuff with the .pcd in rviz. Also you can use the pcd_viewer: `rosrun perception_pcl pcd_viewer <filename>` . Also, you can just try `pcd_viewer filename` if your path is all set right you should be able to visualize it. You can set the coloring using the number keys.

You can get the `pcl_viewer` as well by installing the `pcl_tools` package. Alternatively check [PCL binaries](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/walkthrough.php#binaries).

---

Originally posted by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) with karma: 277 on 2017-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RafMil](https://answers.ros.org/users/30506/rafmil/) on 2018-08-23**:
Hi,
I have tried this solution and encountered difficulties. Error appears: **[pcl::PCDReader::readHeader] No points to read**. Do you have any ideas what might be wrong and how to handle this? Maybe other way of visualization.